# How to stop transparent PNG image showing as black in tableview cell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, uitableview

I have searched SO for an answer but none of them had very complete answers, and none of the suggestions have worked for me.

I have a simple tableview with custom cells in it. One of the cells is filled with a PNG image using an image view. But the transparent background shows as black. I want it to be white.

[image]

I have tried the following, none of which work:
In Interface builder set:
Image background to white.
Background of content view of cell to white.
Background of cell to white.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
The error was on my part. See answer below.

Comment: Are you sure the PNG contains an alpha channel?

Comment: Hmm, not 100% sure. How can I check that? I tested it with x 2 images, one I downloaded from the web. When opened on Mac it has the checkered view indicating transparency. Both images show a black background.

Comment: Ok, Load the image into a paint package like GIMP that will show you the channels...a PNG isn't transparent unless it has been created with an ALPHA channel.

Comment: Ok, I have tested with an image with an alpha channel. Problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was on my part. I was using an extension to transform the image and had set the alpha to false. So I started with a PNG and ended with one without an alpha layer.

Answer (score 2):

Set the table View Cell content view background color to white.

Comment: I have already tried this. Sorry, in my question I said "content view color". Edited now to "content view background color"

Comment: are you using a tableViewController or a viewController??

Comment: A view controller with an embedded tableview.

Comment: set the color of the viewController's View to white. If this also doesn't help then maybe there is a problem with the image. please check

Comment: or use self.view.backgroundcolor = [UIColor whiteColor]; in the viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear()

Comment: I have tried both options: self.viewbackgroundcolor = UIColor.white; and done the same for the background of the the tableview. I have also triple checked the image using multiple images that definitely have transparency layer. None of the solutions work.

Comment: please share the view hierarchy in IB or storyBoard there maybe some issue there then.

Comment: My apologies, i found the problem. I was transforming the image, and in the extension I had set the alpha to false. Sorry for waisting your time. Appreciate the help.